# Why doesn't this function bottom out

Tags: haskell

```
xs = [1, 2] ++ undefined
length $ take 2 $ take 4 xs
```

My brain is reading this as

`length (take 2 ( take 4 xs ) )`

If everything in the parenthesis is evaluated first, then why does this not error out with Exception: prelude.undefined?

The answer given by the book is that take 2 is only taking the first two indices, but shouldn't the take 4 take precedence here and get evaluated first?

Comment: It's not true in Haskell that "Everything in parentheses is evaluated first". Rather the *outermost* expression is generally evaluated first (inner expressions being evaluated when and only if they are needed to "unblock" the evaluation of the outermost expression). That's pretty much what lazy evaluation **is**.

Answer (score 11):

> If everything in the parenthesis is evaluated first, then why does this not error out with `Exception: prelude.undefined`?

Because Haskell is **lazy**. That means it does not evaluate anything unless it is necessary.

Indeed, `length` will need access to the list (but not to its elements if these contain calculations). It will thus ask the `take 2 ( take 4 xs ) )` for the first elements, and then the second, and then the third, etc.

Now `take` is lazy as well. It means as long as it does not need to be evaluated, it will do nothing. In case the `length` asks the next element it will determine that element, if later another element is asked, it will provide the second element for the list. If the `length` asks for another one, then `take 2` will stop, and thus return the empty list.

Haskell thus has not an evaluation strategy like Python or Java where the innermost functions are first evaluated and left to right.

Answer (score 9):

Let's calculate! What is `[1, 2] ++ undefined`? Well, to know that, we first need to know what `[1, 2]` is. It's really just syntactic sugar for `1:2:[]`.

Next, we need to know what `++` is. The [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B) tells us:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[] ++ ys = ys
(x : xs) ++ ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Okay. So let's pattern match.

```
(1:2:[]) ++ undefined
= -- the second pattern matches
1 : (2:[]) ++ undefined
= -- the second pattern matches
1 : 2 : [] ++ undefined
= -- the first pattern matches
1 : 2 : undefined
```

Okay, so we've figured out that

```
xs = 1 : 2 : undefined
```

What about `take 4 xs`? Well, we first have to look at what `take` does. The real source code is somewhat complicated for performance reasons, but we can use this simpler, equivalent, version:

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take n _ | n <= 0 = []
take _ [] = []
take n (a : as) = a : take (n - 1) as
```

So

```
take 4 xs
= -- value of xs
take 4 (1:2:undefined)
= -- 4 is positive, so the first guard falls through.
  -- the second pattern fails (the list isn't empty)
  -- the third pattern succeeds
1 : take 3 (2:undefined)
= -- same analysis
1 : 2 : take 3 undefined
= -- 3 is positive, so the guard fails.
  -- the pattern match on undefined produces undefined
1 : 2 : undefined
```

That's just the same as `xs`!

Next we calculate

```
take 2 (take 4 xs)
= -- as shown above
take 2 (1 : 2 : undefined)
= -- following the same sequence above
1 : take 1 (2 : undefined)
= -- same same
1 : 2 : take 0 undefined
= -- this time the guard succeeds!
1 : 2 : []
= -- reinstalling syntactic sugar
[1, 2]
```

So now you have a fully defined list of two elements, and taking its length poses no special challenge at all.

---

Note that the above is a *calculation*. It does not represent the actual sequence of operations that occur when the program runs. But ... that doesn't actually matter. One of the great things about Haskell is that in your analysis, you can "substitute equals for equals" whenever you want. It won't affect the result. You do have to be a bit careful, however, not to let it confuse you. For example, suppose you want to evaluate `null (repeat ())`. You'd start out something like this:

```
repeat () = () : repeat ()
```

What do you do next? Well, one option is to continue to expand `repeat ()`:

```
repeat () = () : () : repeat ()
```

It's totally valid. But if you keep going on that way forever, you'll never get to an answer. At some point, you have to look at the rest of the problem.

```
null (() : repeat ())
```

is immediately `False`. So just because you can find an infinite sequence of reductions doesn't mean there's an infinite loop. Indeed, the way Haskell works, there's only an infinite loop if *every possible* sequence of reductions is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not forcing the thunk after `take 4 xs`. Consider the following code in the repl

```
Prelude> xs = [1, 2] ++ undefined
Prelude> take 4 xs
[1,2*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\base\GHC\Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:16 in interactive:Ghci1
```

This happens because of the implicit `show` in GHCi. But what if we don't use a bare expression?

```
Prelude> xs = [1, 2] ++ undefined
Prelude> ys = take 4 xs
```

Hey look no error! Let's keep going

```
Prelude> xs = [1, 2] ++ undefined
Prelude> ys = take 4 xs
Prelude> zs = take 2 ys
Prelude> length zs
2
```